# Angular validation for only 1 input field inside a form

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I'm building a form using *Angular 1.1.1* and *Ionic*.

There are many "wallets" and the user needs to send a new "value" to each of the wallet. My form has a validation for all fields which works fine when the 'submit' button for the form is pressed.

However, I also have **a button next to each wallet to send only value to this wallet** (not different values to all wallets). When I press it, all the validation errors appear, but **I need error to be visible only for the particular wallet**.

My form (index.html):

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="sendValues(wallets)" ng-controller="valuesCtrl" novalidate>
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="wallet in wallets">
    <div class="col item item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper item-text-wrap">
        <input name="wallet_{{wallet.id}}" type="number" ng-model="wallet.value" type="text" required/>
      </label>
      <span ng-show="myForm.wallet_{{wallet.id}}.$error.required">!!!</span>
    </div>            
    <div class="col item">{{ wallet.previous }}</div>
    <button ng-click="sendValue(wallet)">
      <i class="ion-android-send"></i>
    </button>
    <span class=ng-show="myForm.$submitted==true && myForm.wallet_{{wallet.id}}.$error.required">Required</span>
  </div>
  <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

My controller (values.js):

```
'Use Strict';
angular.module('App')

.controller('valuesCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage, UserService, $state) {
    $scope.sendValues = function(wallets){
      if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
        ...
      } else {
        $scope.myForm.submitted = true;
      }
    },
    $scope.sendValue = function(wallet){
      if (wallet.value == null) {
        $scope.myForm.submitted = true;
      } else {
        ...
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a form for each wallet

Comment: In this case the validation for all the wallets isn't working

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13696625)

Comment: @Mostafiz this is an answer. Please read [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) and [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your html `name` attributes has same value inside `ng-repeat`

Use $index in your name field for differentiate all the name attribute.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="sendValues(wallets)" ng-controller="valuesCtrl" novalidate>
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="wallet in wallets">
    <div class="col item item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper item-text-wrap">
        <input name="wallet_{{$index}}" type="number" ng-model="wallet.value" type="text" required/>
      </label>
      <span ng-show="myForm.wallet_{{wallet.id}}.$error.required">!!!</span>
    </div>            
    <div class="col item">{{ wallet.previous }}</div>
    <button ng-click="sendValue(wallet)">
      <i class="ion-android-send"></i>
    </button>
    <span class=ng-show="myForm.$submitted==true && myForm.wallet_{{$index}}.$error.required">Required</span>
  </div>
  <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand what should happen, everything acts the same. Why would changing ```wallet.id``` to ```$index``` help? Doesn't ```wallet.id``` differentiate all the name attribute?

Comment: can you provide a codepen plunker example.. Then It will be easy to debug

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a form inside `form` again. But as per HTML standard you can not have nested form. But angular provided that ability to have nested `form` but the inner form should be `ng-form`. Which mean you are going to wrap `form` & inside that you can find multiple `ng-form`'s.

So you should have `ng-form="innerForm"` which will keep track of each repeated form.

Other thing which I observed is, you did mistake while using `ng-show`(you had `{{}}` inside `ng-show` expression, which would not work). To fix it you could access object via its key like `ng-show="innerForm['wallet_'+wallet.id].$error.required"`

**Markup**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="sendValues(wallets)" ng-controller="valuesCtrl" novalidate>
  <div ng-form="innerForm" class="row" ng-repeat="wallet in wallets">
    <div class="col item item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper item-text-wrap">
        <input name="wallet_{{wallet.id}}" type="number" ng-model="wallet.value" type="text" required/>
      </label>
      <span ng-show="innerForm['wallet_'+wallet.id].$error.required">!!!</span>
    </div>            
    <div class="col item">{{ wallet.previous }}</div>
    <button ng-click="sendValue(wallet)">
      <i class="ion-android-send"></i>
    </button>
    <span class=ng-show="innerForm.$submitted==true && innerForm['wallet_'+wallet.id].$error.required">Required</span>
  </div>
  <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation! Do I need to specify ```['wallet_'+wallet.id]``` in ```ng-show="innerForm.$submitted==true ... ```?

Comment: no need to specify there, basically you are verifying whole form.. so its correct

Comment: What about ```$scope.myForm.submitted = true;``` in the controller for inner form? Do I need to remove it?

Comment: @Zelenka that will be there, all the inner form will be wrapped inside `myForm`, if any of the innerForm is invalid then `myForm` will get invalid

Comment: It actually didn't. There are no errors though, so I don't know where's a problem :(

Comment: Could you create a plunkr, so that I can help you further

Comment: Please see the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/8MYGc6VXI7ScCnwKOsG0?p=preview

Comment: I think your solution is good for Angular 1.3+, but I have to use 1.1.1

Comment: @Zelenka Why you consider updating library?